# Outlook VBA Split - breaks the string in two lines

Tags: vba, split, outlook

I have problem with Outlook VBA macro showing a string in one line. The goal is to overwrite existing email body (with some HTML tags, but that's not shown bellow for the sake of simplicity).So let's say we have a String with e.g. 110 characters in objItem.Body. 
The problem is that code down bellow automatically splits the string in two lines (and I want it to be in one line)!

```
Dim strSource As String
Dim aryLines() As String
Dim temp As String

strSource = objItem.Body
aryLines = Split(strSource, vbCrLf)

For i = LBound(aryLines) To UBound(aryLines)
    temp = temp & aryLines(i)
Next i

objItem.HTMLBody = temp
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Why are you splitting a line delimited by a colon into two and then concatenates them back again?
Case 2?
Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please format your code between code tags rather than using HTML? You insert your code via [edit], highlight all the code and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: You are splitting by carriage return in the 2nd, but ; in the first?

Comment: What is your objective? What is the optimal result?

Comment: To Specify, is the string displayed on 2 lines where you are combining them?  Add a debug.print and check for us since we don't have the body of the message please.

Comment: @peakpeak: Now i edited the message. The objective is to put the string into HTML tags, but when doing the body rewrite, the string is broken into two lines for some reason and only for strings longer then 78 characters.

Comment: @Dillon_Su: No, string in the email body (before rewrite) is in one line. That's what is confusing me. Debug.Print does not work in Outlook VBA environment

Comment: Note that `temp = temp & aryLines(i)` should _probably_ be `temp = temp & " " & aryLines(i)` otherwise you'llget yournew messagestring lookinglike this.

Comment: I'm very confused by what you're after. Obviously, you don't want to post an _actual_ email message you're dealing with, but [edit] your message and post a fake sample of input and what your desired output would be. Include very explicit indication of where a line-break would be on both the input and output text so we can best help you.

Comment: @FreeMan: OK. I've a plain text message with a lot of text in format label: value and value is that string that should be rewritten with HTML version. But when I do that, it just breaks the long string (not the short ones) in two columns.

Comment: I'm completely lost as to what you're trying to do here. The HTMLBody should be ***HTML***, which means that line breaks need to be `<br>` or similar. HTML rendering cares nothing about your `vbCrLf`s...

Comment: @AndrewBee - _you've_ got a plain text message, but none of the rest of us can read your mind. Put it in your OP or the best you'll get is some random guesses.

Comment: @FreeMan: objItem.Body is mentioned, which is plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The objective is to put the string into HTML tags, but when doing the body rewrite, the string is broken into two lines for some reason and only for strings longer then 78 characters. – AndrewBee*

The reason you encounter 78 is this:
https://mailformat.dan.info/body/linelength.html

Comment: The solution is to use HTML as the mail format. Plain text format will break at 78 characters in length as Outlook conforms to a number of RFC's

Comment: I guess there is a line break at position 78. This should be easy to debug and then solve

Comment: You mean HTML in the original email (sent from server)? My Outlook is already set to use HTML both o Compose and Message format is set to "Convert to HTML format"

Comment: Please read Vityata's answer. He and I are on the right track. The hint here is that there's a newline character embedded in the current line of the mail message

Comment: I've spotted the problem - during the Body (plain text) splitting it basically takes first 78 characters from the line and stores it in aryLines(i), and other characters (till the end of the line) are stored in the following element aryLines(i+1). Vityata's solution will only work for the manually set String, but not for the one generated from objItem.Body which is plain text.

Comment: Good! You engaged and found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue it lies in how you reassembled/concatenated the variable `temp`.  When you iterated through the array `aryLines()`, you never added a newline.  Consider the code below:

```
Sub oneLineText()
Dim strSource As String
Dim aryLines() As String
Dim temp As String

strSource = "The dog jumped over the fence"
aryLines() = Split(strSource, " ")

For Each ele in aryLines
    temp = temp & ele & " "
next ele

End Sub
```

The result will be the same as the source.  Now, consider the following:

```
Sub multiLineText()
Dim strSource As String
Dim aryLines() As String
Dim temp As String

strSource = "The dog jumped over the fence"
aryLines() = Split(strSource, " ")

For Each ele in aryLines
    temp = temp & ele & vbNewLine
next ele

End Sub
```

This will result in each line containing the `ele` variable on a newline.  As a side note, you can iterate through a variable with `For Each` rather than using `For i = LBound(array) to UBound(array)`.  Every time the loop iterates, the calculation `LBound()` and `UBound()` have to be performed.  Depending on the size of the loop this can lead to considerable processing overhead, however in a shorter loop the cost is negligible.
**EDIT:** Changed sub oneLineText() to include spaces based off FreeMan's comment.

Comment: Actually... `onLineText()` will produce `Thedogjumpedoverthefence`, so it won't _quite_ be the same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the [editions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52499985/revisions) of the question. Thus, I assume that there is some `VbCrLf` in the `objItem.Body`.

Thus with the `Original` it splits the result correctly and the `ShouldWork` returns one line, as the split is done by `VbCrLf` and it is not repeated:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim someInput As String
    someInput = "Sumarum: 531 - Item1 - Item2 - Item3-4. - Item5 - " & vbCrLf & _
        " - Item6 - Item7 - Item8 - Item9 Item10 - Item6 -  -"        
    Debug.Print Original(someInput)
    Debug.Print ShouldWork(someInput)
    Debug.Print Original(someInput) = ShouldWork(someInput)

End Sub

Public Function ShouldWork(someInput As String) As String

    Dim strSource As String
    Dim aryLines() As String
    Dim temp As String, i As Long        
    strSource = someInput
    aryLines = Split(strSource, vbCrLf)        
    For i = LBound(aryLines) To UBound(aryLines)
        temp = temp & aryLines(i)
    Next i        
    ShouldWork = temp

End Function

Public Function Original(someInput As String) As String

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim tt As String: tt = someInput
    Dim temp As String                
    arr = Split(tt, ":")
    temp = temp & arr(0) & ": " & arr(1)
    Original = temp

End Function
```

This is what I get in the immediate window:

[image]

Comment: This works if the string is manually set, but not when the source is objItem.Body

Comment: @AndrewBee - can you print the value of `objItem.Body` and add it to the question?

Comment: I can tell you what I've sent from my Horde account (next comment). The problem is with aryLines = Split(strSource, vbCrLf) because it takes first 78 chars from line and the rest is moved into the next element of aryLines array.

Comment: Sumarum: 531 - Item1 - Item2 - Item3-4. - Item5 - Item6 - Item7 - Item8 - Item9 Item10 - Item6 -  -
Sumarum: 532 - Item1 - Item2 - Item3-4. - Item7 - Item8 - Item9 Item10 - Item6 -  -
Sumarum: 533 - Item1 - Item9 Item10 - Item6 -  -